# ng-show not evaluating $scope.foo.name !== 'root' dynamically added html in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

ng-show not evaluating $scope.foo.name !== 'root' dynamically added html in controller

```
 var button = d3.select("#someId")
                .append("button")
                .attr("class", "button")
                .attr("ng-show","$scope.foo.name !== 'root'")
                .html('{{$scope.foo.name}}').on("click", function(){
                     up($scope.foo);;

        }) .call(function () {
                //$compile(this[0][0].parentElement)($scope);
                $compile(angular.element(this[0][0].parentElement))($scope);

            });
```

Comment: You missed the closing quotation mark in `.attr("class", "button)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `$scope` in your template:

```
.attr("ng-show","foo.name !== 'root'")
.html('{{foo.name}}')
```